# How to write 7th month, 2nd day of year 4714 in lunar calendar?

Tags: translation

My grandpa’s death anniversary is August 4, 2016 and I looked it up to be the 7th month, 2nd day of year 4714  in the lunar calendar. Can someone translate this to the correct way of writing it in Chinese? I want to get it tattooed on but I want to make sure it is correct.

Comment: what does 4714 mean?

Answer (score 4):

think carefully before you "tattoo".

4th august 2016 in lunar calendar is: 丙申歲七月初二

the 4714 is based on "黃帝紀元", a **dubious** "calendar system"; which used 2698 bc as the starting.

as i remembered, i never read any info about it in literatures of yore.

according to the wiki, it was created in 1903. how authentic, and acceptable is in doubt.

[https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/黄帝纪元](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%BB%84%E5%B8%9D%E7%BA%AA%E5%85%83)

if you insist, the above mentioned date in this style is:

黃帝紀元四千七百一十四年七月初二

Answer (score 0):

[Wannianli.net](http://www.wannianli.net/2016/2016-8-4.html) gives:

> 二0一六年七月初二日

(and also: 丙申年乙未月戊午日)

which marks it as 2016 and not 4714, if you really want to write 4714 then you could do something like：

- 四七一四年七月初二日